# How do I set the content of a label to a database table cell in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, database, vb.net, data-binding

I have built a program in WPF using Visual Basic that allows users to select from a series of items. The list of items may change as I add more items or remove older ones. Originally, I would just add and remove these items in the project code, and rebuild the executable.

Over time, however, the list of items grew and became tedious and impractical to maintain in the code. It occurred to me that it would be easier to store the items in a database table which the program can read, and the list can just be updated by adding and removing items from this database.

I have the database built, and I've added it as a Data Source. I have the data connection set up and everything is ready to go.

What I need to know is how to set the `Content` property of a label to a cell from a table in the database. **I want to do this in the codebehind**, not in markup (XAML).

My guess is that I will need to set up a sort of query with a `for` loop to find the cell I want.

The name of the database is `ItemsDB`. It contains a table called `ItemsTable`, and the fields in the table have a unique ID (key) with an `AutoNumber` data type. The column containing the data I want is named `ItemLabel`.

So, to sum it all up, I want a label to show the content from a single cell in the database, specified in the codebehind. Either C# or VB is fine.

### EDIT

I guess I should've mentioned that the labels themselves actually function as buttons, and I don't really want to display a `ListView` if I don't have to. I know it's not helpful to not have any code posted, but I don't even know where to start, so there's no code to post.

Comment: Try this: http://learnwpf.com/post/2007/12/16/What-is-the-equivalent-of-the-ASPNET-Repeater-in-WPF.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but I'm really looking to avoid XAML. All I really use it for in this program is the layout of the UI, while I use the codebehind for all the behavioral things like this.I need something that works exclusively in the codebehind, because I need to call to this from other places in the codebehind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a while longer than I expected, hope this is still useful. So, what you want to do is iterate through a collection and create a new `Label` for each row.
You will need a container for the `Labels`, I used `WrapPanel`, but you can use any `Panel` you want. I'm replacing your `Data Source` with a simple `DataTable`, you'll get the point from this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in YourItemsTable.Rows)
{
    Label newLabel = new Label();
    newLabel.Content = row["ItemLabel"].ToString();
    // If you need some events, attach the handlers here
    yourParentContainerPanel.Children.Add(newLabel);
}
```

This should be all you need.

Comment: Sorry, I posted code with a couple mistakes at first. I corrected it, should work now.

Comment: I'll have to look into this when I get home. Looks promising though!

Comment: Okay, I've set everything up like you said, but the `ListView` is empty. I can't get it to actually fill with the data from the table.

Comment: I've got an idea: If I can actually get the `ListView` to fill with the data from the table, then I can make it invisible and just say `myLabel.Content = myListView.Items.Item(0).ToString()` to get the label to show that item. Right?

Comment: Check that the displaymemberpath property has the correct column name. I tested this with a ListBox instead of ListView and it worked like this. Try with that if it suits your design.

Comment: Just read your edit. You just want to display a button (or label) for each row of data and no list at all? If so, there's a simpler solution. I'll post the code after work.

Comment: Hey, just bumping this comment thread. I've resumed work on this project and would still like to achieve what you stated, if possible. Thank you!